# "Use of closed network connection."

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pem

Our web service developer is getting a "`DeliveryPoint=Unknown Failed:  error on connection with 17.172.233.147:2195: Use of closed network connection. Will retry in 20s`" on my Push Notification Service using Uniqush. I cannot seem to detect which is the problem. Is this a problem with the pem/p12 files or the server cannot reach the Apple gateway? I am not very experienced in push notifications. What could be the common problems if the problem is the pem/p12 files? He is saying that it's the pem/p12 files causing the error. I suspect it is the server where the push notification service is being ran. I tested my pem/p12 files on Pushbots, a popular push notification service and I can receive push notifications with it. So it is a strong guess that the problem is on the push noticication server side.

I also cannot use the tag "Uniqush" here on stackoverflow, it doesn't seem popular. I hope I get help here.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a bit old, but i just had that very same problem.

First, you need to check your certificate and key to be sure to have them both in .pem format, and remove the key password/encription before using them with uniqush.

For detailed instructions go to this blog post and **do steps 4 and 5 only** http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/06/05/how-to-renew-your-apple-push-notification-push-ssl-certificate/
**(steps 1-3 are for renewing your certificate, step 6 is for merging certificate and key which isn't needed for uniqush)**

If you've already done this, maybe the problem aren't the certificates, but a problem in the setup of uniqush.

If this is happening only in Ad-hoc/production environment, after checking that you are using the correct certificates (Ad-hoc/production uses different APNS certs than development), be sure not to include the -sandbox=true when adding the PSP (Push Service Provider) to uniqush.

If the problem persists, maybe yours is the one in this issue https://github.com/uniqush/uniqush-push/issues/47 (my case), so you should try the following:

- Download the latest version of uniqush (1.5.2a5 right now) from http://uniqush.org/downloads/uniqush-push_1.5.2a5_x86_64.tar.gz
- Extract the downloaded file with command `tar zxvf <downloaded_file>`
- Kill uniqush-push process, either using `kill -9 <PID>` or `killall uniqush-push` (you will probably need sudo for both)
- Copy/move `uniqush-push` from extracted folder to `/usr/bin/uniqush-push` (assuming you have it installed here in the first place)
- Run uniqush again with `uniqush-push &` or with a script or something (if you have one already)

Maybe you'll have to re-register the devices that weren't receiving push notifications.

This worked for me, so i hope it helps you.